# Doctrine Embeddables not working with Symfony forms

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

Has anyone encountered this problem when using doctrine embeddables and symfony forms?

> if you don't know Doctrine Embeddables are, you can read about it here
>   http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html

When using value object (CategoryType in my case) with symfony form on form submission (during persisting to DB) I get the following warning

> Warning: ReflectionProperty::getValue() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

This happens because symfony form returns string instead of embeddable object.

The only workaround I have right now is to use `mapped => false` on `type` field and create valid embeddable object inside controller action just before persist. But that's far from "nice" solution and I want to avoid that.

My Entity, Value Object and form (simplified for the sake of question)

*Foo\BarBundle\Entity\CategoryType*

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Entity;

class CategoryType
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $value;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getValue();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

*Foo\BarBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\CategoryType.orm.yml*

```
CategoryType.orm.yml
    Foo\BarBundle\Entity\CategoryType:
        type: embeddable
        fields:
            value:
                type: string
```

*Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Category*

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Entity;

class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @var CategoryType
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Foo\BarBundle\Entity\CategoryType
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Foo\BarBundle\Entity\CategoryType $type
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getName();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

*Foo\BarBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\Category.orm.yml*

```
Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Category:
    type: entity
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        name:
            type: string
    embedded:
        type:
            class: CategoryType
```

*Foo\BarBundle\Form\CategoryType*

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('type')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Category'
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'category_form';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doctrine embedabble behavior is just a persistence mechanism, so, it can not break the form component which is independant from it (and works with all objects graph).

The issue is your form is not well designed (it does not follow your object graph). Here, you have a category which wraps a category type. So, your form must follow the same structure at the definition level.

You must create a `CategoryTypeType` form (mapped to your `CategoryType` class) where your add a `value` field. Then, in your `CategoryType` (the form one), you must embed the `CategoryTypeType` for the `type` field.

Then, the form component will automatically creates a `Category` which wraps a `CategoryType`. Then, Doctrine will simply persists your object as embeddable and everything will work :)